# Anonymous functions, delegates and lambda expressions aren't supported in job method parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hangfire

I'm using Hangfire for the first time on a .Net Core Application... I've written a Job like this:

```cs
using MyTask.Data;
using MyTask.Models;

namespace MyTask
{
    public class CandleStickJob
    {
        private readonly ILogger<CandleStickJob> _logger;
        private readonly CandleStickDbContext _context;

        public CandleStickJob(ILogger<CandleStickJob> logger, CandleStickDbContext context)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _context = context;
        }

        public void CalculateAvgPriceJob()
        {
            try
            {
                var candleSticks = _context.CandleSticks.ToList();

                foreach (var candleStick in candleSticks)
                {
                    double avgPrice = (candleStick.Low + candleStick.High) / 2.0;

                    candleStick.AvgPrice = avgPrice;
                }

                _context.SaveChanges();

                _logger.LogInformation("Successfully updated AvgPrice for all CandleSticks.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Error occurred while calculating AvgPrice");
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then I've used it as a `Controller Action Method`:

```cs
public IActionResult ScheduleAvgPriceJob()
        {
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("CalculateAvgPrice", () => _backgroundJobClient.Enqueue<CandleStickJob>(job => job.CalculateAvgPriceJob()), "*/10 * * * * *");

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

Problem is when I go to Hangfire Dashboard, in recurring jobs tab there is no services and when I've tested it locally with another action method to trigger the method, it throws

```
Anonymous functions, delegates and lambda expressions aren't supported in job method parameters.
```

This is my Hangfire configuration in `Program.cs` file:

```cs
builder.Services.AddHangfire(configuration =>
            {
                configuration
                    .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_180)
                    .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
                    .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
                    .UseSqlServerStorage(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("HangfireConnection"));
            });
```

Comment: What is `_backgroundJobClient` here? This feels a bit odd to have in the lambda. Normally you would use DI to get that injected, so something like `RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IBackgroundJobClient>("CalculateAvgPrice", bjc => bjc.Enqueue<CandleStickJob>(job => job.CalculateAvgPriceJob()), "*/10 * * * * *");` though I would probably also encapsulate that lambda inside a method in the client too. Not sure this answers your question though, just an observation.